# How to calculate max drift along converging lines?

Tags: qgis-3, distance

[image]I have a plot of 2 navigations, red and blue, of two ships that are converging and diverging.  Most of the time they are almost parallel.
Is there a way to calculate the maximum drift along the 2 lines?

NOTE -  the command must take into account the drift over a certain range  only,  say on a 100m range, or else, as there are different passages of the lines, enter image description here the command would see also the farmost drift from lines too far apart... please see the photos

[image: drift between the 2 lines, right and wrong cases]